# smartctl -t long isn't finishing

Tags: hardware, hard-drive, testing, smart, smartctl

I been running `smartctl -t long` on a drive for about 2 days now and it seems to be stalled at 10%. short and conveyance both passed. I have to send 1 of 2 drives purchased back I found badblocks with badblocks (none on this drive and I'ts made over a pass already). I'm just wondering if I should be concerned about this.

```
smartctl 5.39.1 2010-01-28 r3054 [x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-10 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     WDC WD10EARS-00Y5B1
Serial Number:    WD-WMAV51582123
Firmware Version: 80.00A80
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   8
ATA Standard is:  Exact ATA specification draft version not indicated
Local Time is:    Mon May 10 22:19:52 2010 EDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82)     Offline data collection activity
                                    was completed without error.
                                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      ( 241)     Self-test routine in progress...
                                    10% of test remaining.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:             (20100) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                        (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                    command.
                                    Offline surface scan supported.
                                    Self-test supported.
                                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003)     Saves SMART data before entering
                                    power-saving mode.
                                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01)     Error logging supported.
                                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 231) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x3031) SCT Status supported.
                                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       2
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   131   131   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       6408
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       12
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       148
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       10
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       7
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       174
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   106   102   000    Old_age   Always       -       41
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Conveyance offline  Completed without error       00%        99         -
# 2  Extended offline    Interrupted (host reset)      10%        30         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         0         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to have completed.... I guess running badblocks while running `smartctl -t long` causes it either A not to finish or B take longer.